# Microsoft Access subform as a sandbox before actual updating of the data

Tags: ms-access, edit, subform

I have an Access 2013 DB with 2 subforms:  The first one provides current data and the second one I'm trying to set up as a sandbox space for users to make changes and updates at their leisure.  When they are ready to submit those changes and updates they can hit submit and their results will update the current data and table info behind it.

Been a while since I've messed with Access so I can't recall if this can be done so thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can’t be done without a rather messy approach. Forms in access ALWAYS edit ONE row.

What I do in these cases is allow the user to “edit” as much as they please.

However, say we are doing a “classic” check or donation amount enter. So you have a donation amount (say $50), but you THEN have to distributed the amounts to various donation accounts.

With the above, you don’t want to save the data until such time that the amounts distributed to accounts match the donation amount.

Because we can’t contain the form + sub form as a “single” update, then what I do is add a posting flag to the parent form (the one record in the main form).

The user can then edit/add, go away for coffee, and come back and edit some more. You can even come back the next day and continue editing.

Once the user is happy, then you have a post button on the form.

If the user hits post, and the balance amounts don’t match, then you don’t set the postOK flag = true.

The above will thus NOT provide a means for the user to bail out, or un-do their edits to the “whole thing”, but it does allow you to determine that the data entered has been “balanced” and verified. And if the “balance” did not occur, then you can skip that record, or introduce a process in which the data is not posted or marked as done until such time that the data balances.

Here is a screen shot in Access of a “classic” money distribution to several accounts. You can see the donation amount on the left side, and on the right side is the account distribution of that amount.

[image]

However, at the bottom of the screen, for the “job task” the user is working on also has a post button. When they hit the post button, if the amounts don’t balance out, then the posting is NOT yet done. In fact, I let the user enter "many" donations, and then they can "post" all at once for ease and speed of working. The "post" does NOT actually post, but checks the balance. So users "think" they are posting, but it only really ever sets one value (a flag POSTOK).

So to run a report, it can’t be run until such time that the post button was hit.

As noted, this approach will NOT give you a “bail out” option to exit your data entry, nor does it allow you to “undo” the data entry, but it DOES allow you to verify the posting is “ok”, and “valid”. In many cases this approach will suffice.

However, if you looking for some kind of “undo” for the form + sub form edit, then Access quite much is not the correct tool for that type of business model and edit.

Comment: This is great stuff from you both and I appreciate it.  So I ended up going the route of creating the temp table which appears to be working fine.  The problem I'm facing is I'm not putting all my temp table columns (5 total) in the "sandbox" subform (3 columns).  Therefore when a user adds a new row, it doesn't include data for the 2 columns I didn't include in the subform (they are drop downs on the parent form).  I'm pretty sure I'll probably need do some parent child linkage to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you set up a local temp table for the sandbox.

Then when you say 'When they are ready to submit those changes and updates they can hit submit and their results will update the current data and table info behind it.' ….. instead what happens is the Sandbox Temp table record appends or inserts/updates the actual table.

If this is a split multi user app and the Sandbox temp table is local - then the data is indeed temporary and the update must occur within the user's session.  But the overall design is quite simple.

Comment: Well, it still somewhat messy. You have to identify rows in the sub form that been added, those that been edited, and those that been deleted. Not the end of the world, but it still is somewhat messy. If only adding rows to the sub form is "always" the case, then no problem. But deleting rows, or adding rows, and checking changes to existing rows can all be a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

After finally getting back into this I realized I was looking at Access development through the eyes of how I would do it in Excel; both different ecosystems. I took off my Excel forms dev lens and a few things occurred to me that I think may help others with similar struggles:

1. Access and Excel are different VBA development ecosystems.  You can’t necessarily code it in Excel and expect it to work flawlessly in Access.
2. A subform is just a form...and like all forms its controls, code, and behavior don’t change in functionality but in presentation based on form type (datasheet, continuous, etc).
3. Treat each Form and event code independently of each other. If your subform on a parent requires events to kick off when a user adds, updates, deletes, validates, etc.  that code should belong in the form that makes up the subform.....not the parent.
4. The parent form should only control filtering and results from the subform as well as it’s own set of actions the user has.
5. The Screen method is amazing and one I think would have saved my life for tracking changes.  Great link here:  https://www.datawright.com.au/access_resources/tracking_data_changes_in_access.htm